# how to schedule a task to run every n minutes at a specific time (celery-django)

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

When using the celerybeat in django, I would like to schedule a task to start at a specific time, and then run every 5 minutess. I was able to get the task to run every 5 minutes, using crontab(minute='*/5') and this will run after celerybeat is up but i want to run it for example at 8:30, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First you set up your task to run every 5 minutes and you have already done that.

The second step is to wrap the body of your task into a conditional that checks if at the current time it should run or not.
Something like this

```
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

@app.task
def my_task():
    now = timezone.now().time()
    start_time = datetime.time(8, 30, 0)
    end_time = datetime.time(17, 30, 0)
    if now >= start_time and now < end_time:
        # your task ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for because this would require your task to run within certain whole hours and not, as you stated starting in the middle of the hour:

```
crontab(minute='*/5',hour='8,9,10')
```

Building on this though, you could make this work with mutliple statements.

If you wanted it to run from say 8:30 to 11:30, you could do something like this:

```
crontab(minute='30,35,40,45,50,55',hour='8')
crontab(minute='*/5',hour='9,10')
crontab(minute='0,5,10,15,20,25,30',hour='11')
```

You can refer to the docs here https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html